# How is handled auto fill form in Vaadin Framwork

Tags: forms, autocomplete, vaadin

I need to fix error in form. when user enters a birth number. It based on this information fills textfields for sex/ date birth. It is created in Vaadin. Did i miss something. How does it know what is entered and how does it parse ? Is it doing parsing?

Comment: Autofilling is done by the webbrowser. What it enters is dependent on the browser and what values are stored inside the browser. The only thing web developpers can do is telling the browser to turn off autocompletion for that form/field

Comment: Besides what @AndréSchild is pointing out, you should probably take a look at the [field validation chapter from the docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-fields.html).

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific?  Show us your code please or describe your concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i should have to check method for pre - validation first. At the time i asked this, i didn´t know how it is being implemented. Simple parser was used but one check method prevented that from execution. Thanks though.